# iphone “EXC_BAD_ACCESS” when doing sqlite3_open(":memory:", &memory_db)

Tags: iphone, sqlite, memory

While developing for iphone i get “EXC_BAD_ACCESS” when doing

```
    sqlite3         *memory_db;
    if (sqlite3_open(":memory:", &memory_db) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_close(memory_db);
        NSAssert(0, @"Failed to open in-memory database");
}
```

also doing

```
    NSString * memory_db_filename = @":memory:";
    if (sqlite3_open([memory_db_filename UTF8String], &memory_db) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_close(memory_db);
        NSAssert(0, @"Failed to open in-memory database");
    }
```

does not help. Are in-memory sqlite3 databases not available on the iphone?

Any comments are appreciated!

Comment: ':memory:' seems like an odd name for a filename, are you sure it can be created? Why not just called it memory.db or something similar?

Comment: Please post more details about the crash you are seeing (e.g., line number, stack trace, etc.)

Comment: ':memory:' is intended to create an in-memory database. good idea with line number, after checking, i realize the error came from a wrong string with format a few lines further. many thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is not an SQLite3 error code. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327082/exc-bad-access-signal-received).

Comment: Indeed. Sorry, the error came from some lines further in the code, and i didn't realize it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`:memory:` and  `database` are directly supported by ALL sqlite implementations