# randomising questions

Tags: iphone

i am wondering how i can randomise the order of questions when i have `question` as an `NSInteger` i am using the following line of code to try and display my arc4random however it crashes and it doesnt load properly.

```
    question = arc4random() %6 +1;
```

is theere a solution to get the integer question to be randomized in its order?
thanks

Comment: If 'question' is an 'NSInteger', I don't think that's the line that's causing the crash... I could always be wrong, though.

Comment: the actual arc4random doesnt crash something in the statment gives and EXC_BAD_ACCESS error after i run the app for a while.

Comment: Are you using *question* as the index into a 7-element array of questions? If so, that's your problem: The index of the first element in an array is 0, and the index of the 7th element is 6. You're generating numbers from 1 to 7, so whenever you try and access the element with index 7, you're asking for the *8th* element. This will cause an illegal access exception.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're trying to do, but have you definitely added the line `#include` `<stdlib.h>` to the top of your .m file?

Comment: i was missing this that solved the error however i tried replacing my %6 with %question which is also an nsinteger however this doesnt run properly. (again crashes)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have "+1".  Almost certainly you are getting a random number outside of the range of your array, which would seem to be six items long...

Answer (score 0):

Your question appears to be about a crash in your program which displays questions in a random order.  The only line of code you provide calculates a random number 1-7 inclusive.  There is nothing wrong with that line of code.

In a later comment you say that your application crashes with the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.  [This question about the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327082/exc-bad-access-signal-received) indicates that you are crashing from an illegal memory access.  If you want help on this problem, I suggest that you post more code because the error is somewhere else.

Are you looking for something like this?

```
for(int i=0; i<3; i++) { 
   question = arc4random() %6 +1; 
   DisplayQuestion(question); 
}
```

Comment: This is a problem howeverthe code I'm trying to randomize is supposed to select a random question from 1 to 7, however it doesn't really display the correct amount of questions and usually crashes after the first question. Is there a way I can specify this code to randomize for 3 distict randoms from 1-7

Comment: can u please clarify what the i=o, i<3 does?

Comment: This is a for loop.  It is standard C and Objective C notation.  It means start with i = 0 and increment i by one each loop as long as i is less than 3.  That way i take three values 0, 1, and 2.  You said you wanted to display three questions.