# Gesture Recognizer Swipe to Delete From Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, uigesturerecognizer

I'm working on an application that uses core data, and I wanted to add a gesture if the user swipes to the left it will delete the object in the database. I have the gesture recognizer parts all set up, I'm having trouble creating the method to remove the object from the tableview and core data. So if anyone could look at this and point me into the right direction I would appreciate it! Thanks!

TableView.M

```
-(void)swipeleft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
{
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[self tableView] indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

            // Delete object from database
            [context deleteObject:[self.lists objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

            // Remove list from table view
            [self.lists removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        }

@end
```

Error:

```
self(ViewController *)  0x8ea0a90   
indexPath=(NSIndexPath *    )  nil  
context+(NSManagedObjectContext *)  0x8d747f0
```

Comment: What is the problem with what you have? Perhaps you just forgot to call `[context save:nil]` afterwards to save your changes?

Comment: Ok I added that line of code and also added: `[self.tableView reloadData];` Then it started to crash here:`[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];` When I commented that out it worked I just need some sort on animation of the cell fading when deleting.

Comment: Crashes how? Saying what? What exception is raised?

Comment: Are you using a NSFetchedResultsController? If you are, then that's where the deleteRows should happen. If not, you might consider it; it takes care of a lot of problems.

Comment: It's deleting the objects when I remove that line, but when I have it it crashes. I updated the question with the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-(void)swipeleft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[self tableView] indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

        // Delete object from database
        [context deleteObject:[self.lists objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [context save:nil];

        // Remove list from table view
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [self.lists removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Comment: `[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[self.lists objectAtIndex:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];` This is the line causing it to crash when I remove it I'm fine I just no longer have a sliding/deleting animation.

Comment: Received another crash.

Comment: I'm still having this issue.

Comment: Can you give me the crash log?

Comment: check these links   https://discussions.apple.com/message/7461909#7461909    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186251/crash-on-deleterowsatindexpaths