# UITableView EndUpdates is Crashing in ios 8 beta

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8

I have written a code

```
[self.pItemArray insertObject:breakingItem  atIndex:0];
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
[self.pTable beginUpdates];
[self.pTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:array withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.pTable endUpdates];
```

But it crashing only in ios 8 on endUpdtes.

> Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-3302.3.1/UITableView.m:1581

It is working fine in ios7 or lower.

Please help.

Comment: What's the crash error? Is it an exception or an assertion error? What's the console output?

Comment: hi andrew thanks for comment, yes it is the exception.

Comment: Post the complete assertion error. Also try moving the call to `beginUpdates` to before the call to `insertObject:atIndex:`.

Comment: @Saif is this code called on the main thread ?

Comment: hi A-Live. yes it on main thread. it is not crashing in any other iOS version other then ios8.

Comment: i have replaced beginUpdates with reloadTableView, And its working fine.

Comment: Hi i haven't found any solution so replace insertRowAtIndex with Table view reload.

Comment: follow this link, may help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25588779/ios8-swift-deleterowsatindexpaths-crashes