# What is a target dependency?

Tags: xcode

I feel so noob asking this question, but what is a target dependency? I see it all the time in Xcode.

Answer (score 20):

A dependency is another target that must be built before the current target can be. For example, if you have an app target and a framework target, the app target can have the framework target as a dependency, to ensure that the framework is built first. That is, the app target "depends" on the framework.

Answer (score 9):

**Xcode Explicit Dependency**

Xcode `Dependency`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59215808/4770877) is a dependency required to **build** a selected target.

**Explicit dependency**

`Explicit` dependency is a **source code** aka `Non-compiled dependency`. Xcode builds all `explicit dependencies` before the dependent target. `Explicit dependency` overrides `implicit dependency` with the same **product_name**.

`Explicit Dependency` is specified in `Build Phases -> Target Dependencies`.

[image]

There are multiple ways to specify in Xcode that our target depends on other target’s products:

- If a target is located in the **same project**
  No additional setup
- If a targets is located in **different projects** using `cross-project reference`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59218997/4770877)
  Specify search path

Additional notes:

- `Dynamic Framework`

  - You should specify `General -> Embedded Binaries`. If not - on the real device you will get `dyld: Library not loaded`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216661/4770877)
  - If you start adding your dependency from `General -> Embedded Binaries` and select a product that is explicit dependency, Xcode automatically add it into `Build Phases -> Target Dependencies`
- `Static binary`

  - You can fill out only `Build Phases -> Target Dependencies`

[[Implicit dependency]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59218952/4770877)

[[Vocabulary]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216151/4770877)