# Does Swift Package Manager is supported for iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager

Well, I'm building an iOS mobile app with Swift 4 and Xcode 9.

What I'm trying to decide which package manager is better to use: **Carthage**, **CocoaPods** or **Swift Package Manager (SPM)**.

I would rather prefer Carthage over CocoaPods. However, I'm starting looking at SPM. everyone says that will replace CocoaPods.

So I said: Why don't we start using SPM instead of CocoaPods?

**But** the documentation explains:

> Note that at this time the Package Manager has no support for iOS,
>   watchOS, or tvOS platforms.

That quote made me wonder a question:

Does Swift Package Manager is supported for iOS? Is SPM an option for iOS development?

I think there is not much information about SPM.

Thanks!

Comment: I think it just doesn't support building for those platforms. I don't think that stops you from using SPM for downloading and managing third party libraries. Your build process will just need to go through Xcode

Comment: 1 - It is true, but it'll change in the future

Comment: I dont really get it.. it says it doesnt work for those platforms yet. That is totally clear. It is temporary but I dont see how other package managers matter much ;)

Comment: Related: [How do I use Swift Package Manager with an existing macOS project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48837369/how-do-i-use-swift-package-manager-with-an-existing-macos-project). Even though the title is different, you can find relevant iOS information in the answer.

Comment: @Daij-Djan: I've already edited the post. Now there is only one question. Thanks.

Comment: sorry but it reads the same to me and I dont get why the documentation isnt clear. you even got confirmation

Comment: @Daij-Djan I know what you mean, but not support could be also that may be if you have a bug they won't accept your issue because they don't have support for that. Also, if you go to Alamofire github repository for example,  you could find the way to install Alamofire with Swift Package Manger, so... there is the point. If is not possible to use SPM for iOS project, why does Alamofire gives you the way to install their library using Swift Package Manager? It 's not a trivial question, there are lots of user asking the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift Package Manager at this time is only designed to work with everything but iOS.  At this point choose the one you prefer between Carthage or CocoaPods.

Comment: Are you sure about the `only designed to work with Swift Server side projects` part?

Comment: As of today (12/2020) it is now possible: more info in the this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64758546/can-i-specify-a-platform-target-when-running-swift-test-from-the-cli/65256621#65256621