# Xcode 12.5: SPM Dependency Cache Location

Tags: ios, swift, caching, continuous-integration, swift-package-manager

Swift Package Manager got a new [feature in Xcode 12.5](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-12_5-beta-release-notes):

> Swift Package Manager caches package dependencies on a per-user basis, which reduces the amount of network traffic and increases performance of dependency resolution for subsequent uses of the same package. If needed, you can disable cache use in xcodebuild by using the new -disablePackageRepositoryCache flag. (72204929)

I would like to know where this is cached. Maybe we can use this to easily cache those dependencies in continuous environments.

I want to know what is the difference of this change to the behavior before since before there was already a cache folder in DerivedData. So what is the **new** thing here?

Comment: Is this: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjPlcmQjeDuAhVRi1kKHdHtAvsQFjABegQIBxAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fuptech.team%2Fblog%2Fswift-package-manager&usg=AOvVaw0jwco9veFLcdPRVrNPlqoQ what you are looking for?  It looks like they are stored in the ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData system folder.

Comment: I added a paragraph to my question

Comment: I have no idea, but interested too, and asked it on Apple Developer Forums https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/673976

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Xcode 12.5 release notes appear to be referring to `~/Library/Caches/org.swift.swiftpm/`.

Comment: Yes this is true, further information can be found at:
https://forums.swift.org/t/shrinking-toolchain-install-size/44771/3

Comment: do you know how to update this cache folder with command line?

Comment: @QuangHà `xcodebuild` uses `-packageCachePath` option to specify package path.