Xcode "Missing package product 'GoogleUtilities_UserDefaults'" after updating to latest package version using SPM
A few days ago I updated the packages in my swift project to newer versions. I am using the Firebase SDK as well as a few others. Immediately after updating, I got a "Missing package product 'GoogleUtilities_UserDefaults'" error.
After researching this issue, I have attempted:
'File' -> 'Packages' -> 'Reset package Caches'
'File' -> 'Packages' -> 'Resolve package Versions'
'File' -> 'Packages' -> 'Update to latest Package versions'
With no effect.
As suggested by another Stack Overflow answer, I updated specifically to Firebase SDK Version 10.22.1, no luck.
Now I am on SDK version 10.27 (Latest version), same error.
I restarted my Mac (A suggestion on the Apple dev forum), nothing.
Clicking the error message in Xcode just points back to the root project file, and the logs do not provide any clues as to what is referencing this in the project. I assume its the firebase SDK as that is the only Google component in the code. I poked through the github repo for SDK looking for file names or anything related to User defaults and came up empty.
Xcode version 15.3
Any suggestions on where to go next?  Thanks!

Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69308719/833395

@Shivbaba'sson Thank you for the reference answer. I took a look but do not think this is relevant to me, as I am not using any local packages, just pulling firebase SDK from the git repo. I am tempted to remove the package entirely from my project and then re-import it, similar to the suggestions in the solution you sent. Having never attempted this before in xcode, are there any pitfalls I should be worried about?

Check if Xcode 15 resides in Application folder. In my case it was in Downloads folder, moving it to Application folder solved the problem for me. - Someone in Apple Forum

I verified my xcode is in the applications folder. Thanks for the suggestion

Have you tried to clear your derived data and clean project ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62750475/833395

Deleting and reimporting the package worked! now on to the next issue... Thanks everyone for the help!

I was having this issue as well, cleaning the build Product' -> 'Clean Build Folder' then resetting the package cache fixed it for me 'File' -> 'Packages' -> 'Reset package Caches'. I found the answer here(latest reply): https://forums.swift.org/t/missing-package-product-error-for-all-local-swift-packages-when-switching-git-branches/38041/51

Please copy the gist/summary of the answer here

If you have the projectName.xcworkspace file, perhaps you could try deleting it and run pod install, then opening the project again

I had to delete Package.resolved in MyProject.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/swiftpm . Nothing else worked.
