# Redefinition of module 'FBSDKCoreKit' error on React-Native Facebook SDK

Tags: xcode, react-native, facebook-login, facebook-ios-sdk

Having issue like this on build app while trying add facebook sdk and run on simulator:

[image: definition2]
[image: definition1]
[image: definition2]

**Steps i produced:**

1. Installed facebook-ios-sdk via swift package manager
2. Installed react-native facebook sdk package and pod install
3. Made iOS configuration (appdelegate.m && info.plist changes)

And on build, cant beat this error

**What i tried:**

1. I deleted derived data folder & clean build folder & run (million times)
2. pod deintegarate && pod install
3. allowed non-modular includes on pods project build settings
4. rebooted mac completely
5. Defined "~/Documents/FacebookSDK" to framework search paths

**But non of these worked. Its automatically redefining that module and causes this error.**

Defined paths:

/Users/myusername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appfolder/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKCoreKit

And

/Users/myusername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appfolder/Build/Intermediates.noindex/GeneratedModuleMaps/iphonesimulator

Thanks for your assist

Comment: I have the exact same problem: osx: 10.15.4, react-native: 3.2.1, react-native-fbsdk: 2.0.0

Comment: Also I have Xcode: 11.5

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?

Comment: Adding blank swift files as solution below is working for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Remove the facebook-ios-sdk swift package.
2. Create a swift file in project. eg:file.swift
3. Add the YourProjectName-Bridging-Header.h header file in project.
4. clean and run project.

Hope its work!

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? 1. how do you delete `facebook-ios-sdk`, right click delete doesn't have any effect, 2. Where should `File.swift` be located ([here?](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/tree/master/example/ios/RNFBSDKExample), 3. Same, where should it be located?, 4. How do you clean the project?

Comment: 1.For removing swift package see these answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56718121/how-to-delete-swift-package-dependency-in-xcode-11
2.yes you need to create file in project directory.3.when you create swift file in xcode there will a popup show for creating bringing header then click on create it automatically add header 4. Go to product menu and "Clean Build Folder" select that option.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks!
RN - 0.61.5
"react-native-fbsdk": "^2.0.0"

Answer (score 1):

I think [the following](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk#troubleshooting) will solve this particular problem:

> 2. Duplicate symbol errors
>
> - Make sure that `FBSDK[Core, Login, Share]Kit.framework` are **NOT** in `Link Binary with Libraries` for your **root project** when using
>   cocoapods.