# How do I add a framework dependency to a test target?

Tags: xcode, dependency-management

I have created a framework that contains code useful for testing (a bunch of convenience initializers, for example). Now I would like to import that framework in a test target but there doesn't seem to be a way to do this in Xcode. Just importing it with `import Dependency` gives me the "Module not found" error when building.

The General tab of the test target does not have any settings for that (or any settings):

[image]

The Build Phase tab has a Dependencies section, but the framework I want to add does not show up in the list when I press the + button:

[image]

There's also a Link Binary with Libraries section, but when I try to select the framework there Xcode says that file is already being linked (where?):

[image]

I can import and use the framework if I add it in the Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content section of the main target, but I don't want to do this since the framework is meant to be used only in the test code. I don't see the reason to pollute the namespace with all the extra initializers. I could probably try to check if no `XCTest` classes are available at runtime and crash, but that seems like a workaround rather than a solution.

**Any advice?**

P.S. I'm using the latest version of Xcode (11.3.1).

Comment: If you happen to know any good articles or videos on the topic, feel free to share.

Comment: I ran into this as well. I'm curious, are you trying to import a framework that has both ObjC and Swift, and is BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION set to YES? I suspect that such frameworks are not currently useable, because the new .swiftinterface file (Swift 5 "Module Stability") is conflicting with the modulemap for the ObjC.

Comment: Hey! Were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: @learner, no, I wasn't. I'll post an anwer if I find a solution.

Comment: Have you tried adding @testable annotation to the import Dependency statement?

Comment: @learner As far as I remember, it didn't make any difference, the module was not available either way (which makes sense since the containing framework is not linked).

Answer (score 5):

**Xcode 12**

Drag and drop the framework into folder where tests are located.

Go to *YourApp***Tests** target settings: ***Build phases*** -> ***Link Binary With Libraries*** – here your framework should be listed, if not tap on **+** button -> ***Add other*** (on the bottom) and choose your framework from project's test folder

Done!

***PS**: most likely works for Xcode 11 as well*

Answer (score 2):

If you have a source code you are able to use `Explicit dependency`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59219025/4770877) with `cross-project reference`

1. drag and drop dependency project inside a test target
2. Build Phases -> Dependencies -> Plus(If you didn't include dependency into test target on previous step)
3. Import

[[Mixing Objective-C and Swift]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59217109/4770877)