# Obj-C - NSString to int

Tags: objective-c

I'm making this function that takes a string input, converts it to an int, and finds the binary equivalent. It was working an hour ago, but after i tried tinkering with a different keypad, and then going back, it no longer works:

```
 - (void)convertToBinary:(NSString *)tf
    {
      NSString *result = @"";
      NSLog(@"-- %@", tf); //successfully prints
      [tf retain];
      if ([tf isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]){
        NSLog(@"tf is NSString"); //THIS PRINTS SO TF IS CONFIRMED TO BE NSSTRING
       }
      int dec = [tf intValue]; //BREAKS HERE...!

      if (!dec){
        [binaryOutput setText:@"Sorry, invalid input!"];
        } else {
              ...
        }

}
```

I know that to convert an NSString to an int, i just need to do `int dec = [someString intValue]` yet that isn't working. The error i'm getting is `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS`

Any help please?

EDIT

I just made a small command-line project:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    // insert code here...
    NSString *t = @"123";
    int d = [t intValue];
    NSLog(@"Hello, %@", d);
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

and the EXEC_BAD_ACCESS still persists for such a simple program! What's the problem here?

Comment: The reason why it crashes in your command-line project is, that you use the wrong format string. use @"Hello, %d" instead of @"Hello, %@"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using "%d" when printing integers. Change the line to:

```
NSLog(@"Hello, %d", d);
```

Comment: this is such an amateur move on my end, but while i was debugging, i inserted NSLog(@"%@", dec) and didn't see it was causing the exec-bad-access. thanks

Comment: Sometimes it happens, np. Take care.

Answer (score 1):

`EXEC_BAD_ACCESS` usually fires when there is a memory leak, check that tf is not null or released.
You can write `NSLog(@"%@", tf);` at the beginning of the method to check that.

Comment: Just check tf with NSLog, and it prints out fine. My method is very simple and doesn't use any alloc. Would i need to retain or copy?

Comment: no luck. I made a simple helloWorld where i convert a string to an int and the problem persists. Your two cents?

Comment: EXEC_BAD_ACCESS is not the result of a leak, but most likely caused by sending a message to an already released object. A leak happens if you have lost reference to an object.

Answer (score 1):

As edo42 it's probably related to a null/released string. See "[EXC_BAD_ACCESS signal received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327082/exc-bad-access-signal-received)" for lots of information about that error message, and how to [debug using NSZombieEnabled](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?DebuggingAutorelease).

Answer (score 1):

Instruments.app with the Zombies instrument might help to uncover the crash.  Also try a "Build and Analyze" run.