# Variables reset after calling with IBAction

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, variables

In Objective-c, I have variables set in the interface file:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface TestApp_BotAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> 
    {
   NSString * someString;
    }
- (IBAction) doSomething:(id)sender;

@end
```

And have this

```
#import "TestApp_BotAppDelegate.h"
@implementation TestApp_BotAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize Buildings;
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
    {
    someString=@"HELLO";
    }

- (IBAction) doSomething:(id) sender
    {
    NSLog(@"%@", someString);
    }
@end
```

When i call doSomething from a button in the UI, I get a bad access error.

I know you that this is supposed to happen, but I don't know why or a workaround.

Thanks, 
Will

---

Comment: The problem is elsewhere

Comment: Please post the error message that you get.

Comment: Have you checked to see if applicationDidFinishLaunching is called with a NSlog? Also, always check to see if a pointer variable you're about to use is not nil with an if statement, e.g. if(someString){NSLog(@"%@", someString)}

Comment: @Miniroo: Please post any code that accesses or modifies someString.

Comment: @Mark: Even if it is NULL/nil, the NSLog will print (null).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a bad access error because the string is not being properly managed in memory as explained in this question: [EXC_BAD_ACCESS signal received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327082/exc-bad-access-signal-received). According the the code you posted you are never allocing and initializing someString, and therefore never releasing it. I believe you are not receiving null because the someString object never is taking up any memory to begin with.