# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in protocol?

Tags: iphone, delegates, protocols

I am getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS at the following line, what can be possbile reason, can any one explain

```
    if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(dealInfo:imageDidDownload:indexPath:)])//Here is EXC_BAD_ACCESS

    [self.delegate dealInfo:self imageDidDownload:thumbImage indexPath:self.indexPath];
```

I have done deal.delegate=self;, and deal is declared in delegate method of UITableView

```
      cellForRowAtIndexPath
```

something like below

```
    DealInfo *deal = [nearByDeals objectAtIndex:(section - 1)];
    deal.delegate = self;
    deal.indexPath = indexPath;
```

HELP!

Comment: possible duplicate of [EXC_BAD_ACCESS signal received](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327082/exc-bad-access-signal-received)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EXC_BAD_ACCESS usually means you're trying to access a released object. In this case, delegate is probably released before you call `respondsToSelector:` on it.

Comment: But what can I do, I have to use object in cellForRowAtIndexPath, which creates objects at same time, one by one, ?

Comment: Can you tell me solution for resolving it?

Comment: @vikingosegundo, a bit, but not more, can you explain any solution if I have use protocol in delegate methods?

Comment: Sure — get familiar with memory management and properties. And post your code, where you intanciate the delegate.