# Crash in COCOA framework inside, how to debug?

Tags: cocoa-touch, debugging, crash

Hello you smart guys;

Confused on how to fix such crash, it is random. Could you give me some tips? How to debug? What's the potential root cause?

Need some tips when crash on COCOA framework inside. Any ideas and discussion will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

[image: Crash call stack]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me that stack trace looks like an dealloced view or layer is accessed by a tableView. To debug such a situation there is NSZombie. Read [how to enable NSZombie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode).

When running with NSZombie no object is ever removed from memory. Instead dealloced objects are turned into zombies. They keep hanging around and when accessed you can examine them to find out were they where instantiated and when they were retained and released during their lifetime. That should give you a good idea where to look for the problem.

More info on that specific problem may be found at [EXC_BAD_ACCESS signal received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327082/exc-bad-access-signal-received) .

More general debugging information can be found in [TN2239 iOS Debugging Magic](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2239/_index.html).

Comment: Thanks you guy's kindly response. Check with NSZombie is really a very useful method.