# what is the effect of this error on my program? “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”. sharedlibrary

Tags: objective-c, xcode3.2

I am writing a program using MAC OSX 10.6.6 and xcode 3.2

I have this Error:

> Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”. sharedlibrary
>   apply-load-rules all

but my code runs and works well, should i be worry about this message?

Comment: definitely. Are you sure it hasn't crashed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you should be.  This is an indication that there is a memory issue, most likely due to referencing an object that has been released, more often than not, by an autoreleased object.

Here's a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327082/exc-bad-access-signal-received) that I think will prove helpful.