# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on setMask

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to apply a mask to both a base layer and a background layer, but the solutions below blows up when setting the mask on either layer.
Could anyone please let me know what I'm doing wrong?

```
self.backLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
[self.backLayer setBounds:[self bounds]];
[self.backLayer setPosition:CGPointMake([self bounds].size.width/2, [self bounds].size.height/2)];
self.backLayer.opacity = 0.3f;
[[self layer] insertSublayer:self.backLayer atIndex:0];

[[self layer] setMasksToBounds:YES];
[[self layer] setBorderWidth:0.0f];

UIBezierPath* path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:[self bounds]];
self.backLayer2 = [CAShapeLayer layer];
self.backLayer2.path = path.CGPath;
self.layer.mask = self.backLayer2;
self.backLayer.mask = self.backLayer2;
CGPathRelease(path.CGPath);
```

Comment: once check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327082/exc-bad-access-signal-received

Comment: Already did. Doesn;t apply.

Comment: Show the full stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you are not supposed to release the CGPath of a UIBezierPath. So, the line

```
CGPathRelease(path.CGPath);
```

releases memory the object tries to also release later, causing a memory violation.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your code posted is perfect. There is no problem with the code. The `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` will occur if you perform any action on deallocated object.
Please make sure the `self object/view` is not deallocated by `ARC`. Check the place where you declared the view is still alive in `stack/memory`.
Dont forget to check the property declaration parameters (`Strong/weak/noatomic`) for backLayer property.