# AFNetworking issues on Ios 8

Tags: ios8, arm, afnetworking

When i try to call a java/soap web service from iOS (objective c) using AFNetworking, after many times I get this error: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" 
on 0x71d678: ldr  r0, [r4, #0x68].
But I noticed that if on iPhone (particularly iphone 6 or in generally on iOS8) I disable WIFI the error disappeared
I post the assembly code

```
libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_timers_run:
0x71d5f0:  push   {r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}
0x71d5f2:  add    r7, sp, #0xc
0x71d5f4:  push.w {r8, r10, r11}
0x71d5f8:  sub    sp, #0x18
0x71d5fa:  movs   r6, #0x0
0x71d5fc:  str    r0, [sp]

0x71d5fe:  movw   r0, #0xa83e
0x71d602:  movt   r0, #0x1
0x71d606:  add    r0, pc
0x71d608:  add.w  r1, r0, r6, lsl #6
0x71d60c:  ldr    r0, [r1, #8]!
0x71d610:  str    r1, [sp, #0x14]
0x71d612:  cmp    r0, #0x0
0x71d614:  beq.w  0x71d776                  ; _dispatch_timers_run + 390
0x71d618:  ubfx   r4, r6, #0x2, #0x1
0x71d61c:  ldr    r5, [sp]
0x71d61e:  cbz    r5, 0x71d632              ; _dispatch_timers_run + 66
0x71d620:  ldr.w  r0, [r5, r4, lsl #3]
0x71d624:  str    r0, [sp, #0x10]
0x71d626:  cbz    r0, 0x71d632              ; _dispatch_timers_run + 66
0x71d628:  add.w  r0, r5, r4, lsl #3
0x71d62c:  ldr    r0, [r0, #0x4]
0x71d62e:  str    r0, [sp, #0xc]
0x71d630:  b      0x71d664                  ; _dispatch_timers_run + 116
0x71d632:  cmp    r4, #0x0
0x71d634:  bne    0x71d63c                  ; _dispatch_timers_run + 76
0x71d636:  bl     0x70df20                  ; _dispatch_get_nanoseconds
0x71d63a:  b      0x71d648                  ; _dispatch_timers_run + 88
0x71d63c:  cmp    r4, #0x1
0x71d63e:  str    r0, [sp, #0x10]
0x71d640:  str    r0, [sp, #0xc]
0x71d642:  bne    0x71d64c                  ; _dispatch_timers_run + 92
0x71d644:  blx    0x72b380                  ; symbol stub for: mach_absolute_time
0x71d648:  str    r0, [sp, #0x10]
0x71d64a:  str    r1, [sp, #0xc]
0x71d64c:  cbz    r5, 0x71d664              ; _dispatch_timers_run + 116
0x71d64e:  ldr    r0, [sp, #0x10]
0x71d650:  ldr    r1, [sp, #0xc]
0x71d652:  str.w  r0, [r5, r4, lsl #3]
0x71d656:  add.w  r0, r5, r4, lsl #3
0x71d65a:  str    r1, [r0, #0x4]
0x71d65c:  b      0x71d664                  ; _dispatch_timers_run + 116
0x71d65e:  mov    r0, r4
0x71d660:  bl     0x71c5bc                  ; _dispatch_timers_update
0x71d664:  ldr    r0, [sp, #0x14]
0x71d666:  ldr.w  r10, [r0]
0x71d66a:  cmp.w  r10, #0x0
0x71d66e:  beq.w  0x71d776                  ; _dispatch_timers_run + 390
0x71d672:  ldr.w  r0, [r10, #8]
0x71d676:  mvns   r4, r0
0x71d678:  ldr    r0, [r4, #0x68]
0x71d67a:  cmp    r0, r6
0x71d67c:  bne    0x71d65e                  ; _dispatch_timers_run + 110
0x71d67e:  mov    r8, r10
0x71d680:  ldr    r5, [r8, #24]!
0x71d684:  ldr    r2, [sp, #0x10]
0x71d686:  ldr.w  r11, [r8, #4]
0x71d68a:  subs   r0, r5, #0x1
0x71d68c:  sbc    r1, r11, #0x0
0x71d690:  cmp    r0, r2
0x71d692:  mov.w  r0, #0x0
0x71d696:  it     hs
0x71d698:  movhs  r0, #0x1
0x71d69a:  ldr    r2, [sp, #0xc]
0x71d69c:  cmp    r1, r2
0x71d69e:  mov.w  r1, #0x0
0x71d6a2:  it     hs
0x71d6a4:  movhs  r1, #0x1
0x71d6a6:  it     eq
0x71d6a8:  moveq  r1, r0
0x71d6aa:  cmp    r1, #0x0
0x71d6ac:  bne    0x71d776                  ; _dispatch_timers_run + 390
0x71d6ae:  ldr    r0, [r4, #0x1c]
0x71d6b0:  cmp    r0, #0x1
0x71d6b2:  bhi    0x71d65e                  ; _dispatch_timers_run + 110
0x71d6b4:  ldr    r0, [r4, #0x70]
0x71d6b6:  cmp    r0, #0x0
0x71d6b8:  bne    0x71d65e                  ; _dispatch_timers_run + 110
0x71d6ba:  str    r6, [sp, #0x4]
0x71d6bc:  ldr.w  r6, [r10, #48]
0x71d6c0:  ldr.w  r3, [r10, #52]
0x71d6c4:  ldr    r0, [sp, #0x10]
0x71d6c6:  ldr    r1, [sp, #0xc]
0x71d6c8:  mov    r2, r6
0x71d6ca:  str    r3, [sp, #0x8]
0x71d6cc:  subs   r0, r0, r5
0x71d6ce:  sbc.w  r1, r1, r11
0x71d6d2:  blx    0x72b240                  ; symbol stub for: __udivdi3
0x71d6d6:  mov    r9, r6
0x71d6d8:  adds   r6, r0, #0x1
0x71d6da:  adc    r12, r1, #0x0
0x71d6de:  lsrs   r1, r6, #0x1f
0x71d6e0:  orr.w  r1, r1, r12, lsl #1
0x71d6e4:  movs   r2, #0x0
0x71d6e6:  mvn    r3, #0x80000000
0x71d6ea:  orr.w  r1, r1, r12, lsr #31
0x71d6ee:  cmp    r1, #0x0
0x71d6f0:  mov.w  r1, #0x0
0x71d6f4:  itt    ne
0x71d6f6:  movne.w r12, #0x0
0x71d6fa:  mvnne  r6, #0x80000000
0x71d6fe:  cmp.w  r9, #0xffffffff
0x71d702:  it     eq
0x71d704:  moveq  r1, #0x1
0x71d706:  ldr    r0, [sp, #0x8]
0x71d708:  cmp    r0, #0x0
0x71d70a:  it     lt
0x71d70c:  movlt  r2, #0x1
0x71d70e:  cmp    r0, r3
0x71d710:  it     eq
0x71d712:  moveq  r2, r1
0x71d714:  mov    r3, r0
0x71d716:  cbnz   r2, 0x71d73c              ; _dispatch_timers_run + 332
0x71d718:  umull  r1, r2, r6, r9
0x71d71c:  mla    r2, r6, r3, r2
0x71d720:  mla    r0, r12, r9, r2
0x71d724:  adds   r2, r1, r5
0x71d726:  adc.w  r3, r0, r11
0x71d72a:  strd   r2, r3, [r8]
0x71d72e:  ldrd   r0, r1, [r10, #56]
0x71d732:  adds   r0, r0, r2
0x71d734:  adcs   r1, r3
0x71d736:  strd   r0, r1, [r10, #32]
0x71d73a:  b      0x71d750                  ; _dispatch_timers_run + 352
0x71d73c:  mov.w  r0, #0xffffffff
0x71d740:  str.w  r0, [r8]
0x71d744:  str.w  r0, [r8, #4]
0x71d748:  str.w  r0, [r8, #8]
0x71d74c:  str.w  r0, [r8, #12]
0x71d750:  mov    r0, r4
0x71d752:  bl     0x71c5bc                  ; _dispatch_timers_update
0x71d756:  ldr    r0, [sp, #0x10]
0x71d758:  ldr    r1, [sp, #0xc]
0x71d75a:  strd   r0, r1, [r10, #40]
0x71d75e:  ldrex  r0, [r4, #0x70]
0x71d762:  add    r0, r6
0x71d764:  strex  r1, r0, [r4, #0x70]
0x71d768:  cmp    r1, #0x0
0x71d76a:  bne    0x71d75e                  ; _dispatch_timers_run + 366
0x71d76c:  mov    r0, r4
0x71d76e:  bl     0x715934                  ; _dispatch_wakeup
0x71d772:  ldr    r6, [sp, #0x4]
0x71d774:  b      0x71d664                  ; _dispatch_timers_run + 116
0x71d776:  adds   r6, #0x1
0x71d778:  cmp    r6, #0x7
0x71d77a:  bne.w  0x71d5fe                  ; _dispatch_timers_run + 14
0x71d77e:  add    sp, #0x18
0x71d780:  pop.w  {r8, r10, r11}
0x71d784:  pop    {r4, r5, r6, r7, pc}
0x71d786:  nop
```

Can someone help me, please?
On iphone 4s it's ok (iOS 7)
Thank you in advance
Claudio

Comment: possible duplicate of [EXC\_BAD\_ACCESS signal received](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327082/exc-bad-access-signal-received)

Comment: This isn't really about assembly, it's just about dereferencing a bad pointer (possibly failing to check an object is valid before calling a method on it?)