# UIFont Class Crashed app in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, class, uifont

I have a UIFont Class that looks like this:

```
struct FontHelper {
    func defaultFont(size: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
        return UIFont(name:"Helvetica", size: size)!
    }
}
```

and I call the method like this"

```
let fonts = FontHelper.defaultFont(12)
```

However my app crashes with an unexpected found nil while wrapping optional?

Have no idea why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're adding your own personal functionality to a *Type*, I think you should use an ***extension***, declare this ***extension*** outside of your class:

```
extension UIFont {
    // You can set a default value for the size if the user doesn't provide one.
    class func defaultFont(_ size: CGFloat = 12) -> UIFont {
        return UIFont(name:"Helvetica", size: size)!
    }
}
```

Now, the **UIFont** *Type* has this really cool functionality you just added.

Within your class, call it:

```
let font = UIFont.defaultFont(12)
```

I hope you can see the power of ***extensions*** here, so take advantage of them in *Swift*!

Comment: I think this is the best solution.  This solution is especially convenient for other UIKit classes like `UIColor`, where we're already used to things like `UIColor.blackColor()`, for example.  No way to add custom colors like that without extensions.

Answer (score 4):

Its should be called like this

```
let fonts =  FontHelper().defaultFont(mySize)
```

Comment: While this answer solves the problem, I think I much prefer Justin Rose's answer regarding using extensions.  It's much nicer.  Also, I think we could probably just declare the struct's method as being `static`, which would also be preferred to this.  We really don't have to instantiate the struct.... but +1 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

When u work with `UIFont(name:"HelveticaCE-Regular", size:14.0)`

I believe iOS requires the PostScript name for a font when using `fontWithName: size:`, which you can find/verify by opening the font in **Apple's Font Book** and typing command+I.

Maybe this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If you add custom fonts manually to your project, you need to register the fonts before use it in runtime:

```swift
func loadFont(withName fontName: String) {
    guard let fontURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fontName, withExtension: "ttf"),
          let fontData = try? Data(contentsOf: fontURL) as CFData,
          let provider = CGDataProvider(data: fontData),
          let font = CGFont(provider) else { return }
    CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(font, nil)
}

// For example, this array need to contain the fonts filenames without extension.
let fontNames = ["Roboto-Black", "Roboto-Regular", "Roboto-Bold"]

for fontName in fontNames {
    loadFont(withName: fontName)
}
```