# When opening app KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS

Tags: ios, xamarin

Yesterday our app's latest version made it the app store. Since then, some users immediately get forced off the app when they try to open it. One of our testers was able to recreate on one of her devices. After symbolicating her logs, here are the results (sorry for the nasty stack):

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
System_Data_DataRow_EndEdit (DataRow.cs:843)
    System_Data_SqlTypes_SqlMoney_op_LessThan_System_Data_SqlTypes_SqlMoney_System_Data_SqlTypes_SqlMoney (SQLMoney.cs:446)
Mobile_iOS_Views_TodaysListings_TodaysListingsTableViewController__CreateViewControllerAsyncc__AnonStorey2__CreateViewControllerAsyncc__AnonStorey0__m__1 (TodaysListingsTableViewController.cs:142)

System_Data_DataSet_InternalEnforceConstraints (DataSet.cs:209)
System_Collections_Generic_Dictionary_2_long_Mono_Data_Sqlite_SqliteFunction_AggregateData_Insert_long_Mono_Data_Sqlite_SqliteFunction_AggregateData (dictionary.cs:357)
System_Collections_Generic_Dictionary_2_long_Mono_Data_Sqlite_SqliteFunction_AggregateData_Insert_long_Mono_Data_Sqlite_SqliteFunction_AggregateData (dictionary.cs:352)
Mobile_iOS_Controls_Favorites_FavoritesActionSheet_HandleSheetDismissed_object_UIKit_UIButtonEventArgs (FavoritesActionSheet.cs:184)
System_Text_RegularExpressions_RegexInterpreter_Go (RegexInterpreter.cs:929)
Mobile_iOS_Controls_Property_PropertyToolbarItem_FromBarButtonItem_UIKit_UIBarButtonItem (PropertyToolbarItem.cs:104)

Thread 0 name: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
Views_Search_SearchListViewController_get_RowSelectedDelegate (SearchListViewController.xib.cs:62)
ApplicationDelegate_WaitForNetwork_System_Action (ApplicationDelegate.cs:879)
System_Array_qsort_intptr_intptr___int_int_System_Collections_Generic_IComparer_1_intptr (Array.cs:2445)
GeocoderResult_SetAccuracy (Geocoder.cs:187)
GeocoderResult_SetAccuracy (Geocoder.cs:187)
ApplicationDelegate_GetBundleVersion (ApplicationDelegate.cs:1115)
ApplicationDelegate_WaitForNetwork_System_Action (ApplicationDelegate.cs:879)
System_Array_qsort_intptr_intptr___int_int_System_Collections_Generic_IComparer_1_intptr (Array.cs:2445)
GeocoderResult_SetAccuracy (Geocoder.cs:187)
GeocoderResult_SetAccuracy (Geocoder.cs:187)
GeocoderResult_SetAccuracy (Geocoder.cs:187)
GeocoderResult_SetAccuracy (Geocoder.cs:187)
GeocoderResult_SetAccuracy (Geocoder.cs:187)
GeocoderResult_SetAccuracy (Geocoder.cs:187)
wrapper_managed_to_native_System_Net_Sockets_Socket_Shutdown_internal_intptr_System_Net_Sockets_SocketShutdown_int_ (Socket_2_1.cs:1402)
GeocoderResult_SetAccuracy (Geocoder.cs:187)
System_Text_RegularExpressions_RegexInterpreter_Go (RegexInterpreter.cs:929)
GeocoderResult_SetAccuracy (Geocoder.cs:187)
GeocoderResult_SetAccuracy (Geocoder.cs:187)
GeocoderResult_SetAccuracy (Geocoder.cs:187)
GeocoderResult_SetAccuracy (Geocoder.cs:187)
GeocoderResult_SetAccuracy (Geocoder.cs:187)
GeocoderResult_SetAccuracy (Geocoder.cs:187)
GeocoderResult_SetAccuracy (Geocoder.cs:187)
xamarin_fpret_double_trampoline (.monotouch-trampoline-writeback.inc:59)
GeocoderResult_SetAccuracy (Geocoder.cs:187)
Controls_Property_PropertyToolbarItem_FromBarButtonItem_UIKit_UIBarButtonItem (PropertyToolbarItem.cs:104)
GeocoderResult_SetAccuracy (Geocoder.cs:187)
ApplicationDelegate_CreateSession_Configuration_HostDefinition_int (ApplicationDelegate.cs:1000)

Thread 1 name: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
SearchCriteriaTableViewSource_NumberOfSections_UIKit_UITableView (SearchCriteriaTableViewSource.cs:183)
ApplicationDelegate_HandleLoginNotification_Foundation_NSNotification (ApplicationDelegate.cs:580)

Thread 2:
Views_Search_SearchListViewController__Disposem__2 (SearchListViewController.xib.cs:216)

Thread 3:
Views_Search_SearchListViewController__Disposem__2 (SearchListViewController.xib.cs:216)

Thread 4:
GeocoderResult_SetAccuracy (Geocoder.cs:187)
GeocoderResult_SetAccuracy (Geocoder.cs:187)
GeocoderResult_SetAccuracy (Geocoder.cs:187)
GeocoderResult_SetAccuracy (Geocoder.cs:187)
ApplicationDelegate_HandleLoginNotification_Foundation_NSNotification (ApplicationDelegate.cs:590)
ApplicationDelegate_HandleLoginNotification_Foundation_NSNotification (ApplicationDelegate.cs:582)


Thread 5:
Views_Search_SearchListViewController__Disposem__2 (SearchListViewController.xib.cs:216)

Thread 6:
Views_Search_SearchListViewController__Disposem__2 (SearchListViewController.xib.cs:216)

Thread 7:
Views_Search_SearchListViewController__Disposem__2 (SearchListViewController.xib.cs:216)

Thread 8 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 8:
System_Net_FtpWebRequest_OperationCompleted (FtpWebRequest.cs:906)
System_Net_DigestHeaderParser__ctor (DefaultCertificatePolicy.cs:52)
Views_Search_SearchMapSettingsViewController_Handle_applyButton_TouchDown_object_System_EventArgs (SearchMapSettingsViewController.xib.cs:55)
Views_Search_SearchMapSettingsViewController__ctor_Foundation_NSCoder (SearchMapSettingsViewController.xib.cs:27)
plt_REModel_Forms_Renderer_3_System_IOWriter_REModel_Forms_HtmlRenderer_FormItemHtmlRenderer_get_Depth + 8
System_Net_HttpWebResponse_System_Runtime_Serialization_ISerializable_GetObjectData_System_Runtime_Serialization_SerializationInfo_System_Runtime_Serialization_StreamingContext (HttpWebResponse.cs:275)
ApplicationDelegate_HandleLoginNotification_Foundation_NSNotification (ApplicationDelegate.cs:590)
ApplicationDelegate_HandleLoginNotification_Foundation_NSNotification (ApplicationDelegate.cs:582)
```

So I know this is probably very similar to this [EXC_BAD_ACCESS signal received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327082/exc-bad-access-signal-received) and other issues related to "KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS", however, I have not been able to recreate this on my own device or on a simulator. This happens exclusively to some users who just downloaded our latest version. As such, I am unable to use `NSZombieEnabled` to find the origin.

Note that this latest release included the upgrades necessary for the Xamarin Unified Api.

I am not a pro to iOS or to Xamarin. Does anything in the stack look like it could be the cause? Any other tricks to see what is going on?

Comment: It's a null pointer exception, probably in C or C++.  Very common but not something we can easily help you find.

Comment: I am curious, why do you think it is in C or C++? This is written using Xamarin which essentially wraps Objective-C code inside C# code. Thanks for your help @trojanfoe.

Comment: Because calling a method (or rather "sending a message") on a `nil` object is silently ignored in Objective-C.

Comment: Did you double check the files and line numbers mentioned in the stack trace?

Comment: Yes, @der_michael. They were not useful.