# 'EXC BAD ACCESS' error in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access

How does EXC BAD ACCESS occur ?
Is it regarding the situation while we are trying to access a variable that is already released ?

Comment: Please share the code where you are facing this error

Comment: This is not a place to ask general question

Comment: ok sir !! 
Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers

Answer (score 1):

As the name signify this error comes when application is trying to access a memory location that does not exists (majorly caused when trying to access a object that is already released). You can get a detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327082/exc-bad-access-signal-received).