# IPhone App crashing if downloaded from app store but not from testflight

Tags: ios, iphone

I done with development process of the app, and it pass the validation. It is running on iphone 5 with ios 9.1 everything was working fine using testflight. But now when I download store version crash. I am confused with reason behind crashing. I am certain it is not an issue with the code because same code is working fine if i directly install through xcode. whats the difference  installing app through testflight/XCode  and store ? What might be the problem ? I do not know how to fix it, I would appreciate any help. The error log:

---

```
    Date/Time:           2015-11-10 14:05:50.50 +0100
    Launch Time:         2015-11-10 14:05:39.39 +0100
    OS Version:          iOS 9.1 (13B143)
    Report Version:      105

    Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
    Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x1c7a0365
    Triggered by Thread:  0

    Filtered syslog:
    None found

    Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
    0.388890     CFNetwork                  0x00000000266f591d TCP Conn 0x1751b340 started
    0.399326     CFNetwork                  0x000000002673640f Creating default cookie storage with default identifier
    0.399326     CFNetwork                  0x00000000267363eb Faulting in CFHTTPCookieStorage singleton
    0.399326     CFNetwork                  0x000000002677878b Faulting in NSHTTPCookieStorage singleton



    Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    Thread 0 Crashed:
    0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x387d7af6 objc_msgSend + 22
    1   Vivimat                         0x0009aa1c 0x8d000 + 55836
    2   Vivimat                         0x0009a708 0x8d000 + 55048
    3   Vivimat                         0x000ff2f8 0x8d000 + 467704
    4   Vivimat                         0x000fefe8 0x8d000 + 466920
    5   Vivimat                         0x000fa798 0x8d000 + 448408
    6   Vivimat                         0x000fab12 0x8d000 + 449298
    7   Vivimat                         0x000fbc14 0x8d000 + 453652
    8   Vivimat                         0x000d5360 0x8d000 + 295776
    9   libdispatch.dylib               0x38eefe2e _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
    10  libdispatch.dylib               0x38eefe1a _dispatch_client_callout + 22
    11  libdispatch.dylib               0x38ef46c8 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1532
    12  CoreFoundation                  0x26e18534 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
    13  CoreFoundation                  0x26e16a2e __CFRunLoopRun + 1590
    14  CoreFoundation                  0x26d690d8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 516
    15  CoreFoundation                  0x26d68ecc CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
    16  GraphicsServices                0x300deaf8 GSEventRunModal + 160
    17  UIKit                           0x2aff22dc UIApplicationMain + 144
    18  Vivimat                         0x000a16d2 0x8d000 + 83666
    19  libdyld.dylib                   0x38f18872 start + 2

    Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
    Thread 1:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38fe9320 kevent_qos + 24
    1   libdispatch.dylib               0x38eff9a6 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 254
    2   libdispatch.dylib               0x38ef1a86 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 38

    Thread 2:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38fe888c __workq_kernreturn + 8
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39084e18 _pthread_wqthread + 1036
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x390849fc start_wqthread + 8

    Thread 3 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos
    Thread 3:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38fd400c semaphore_wait_trap + 8
    1   libdispatch.dylib               0x38efda1e _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 190
    2   CFNetwork                       0x266bbcdc CFURLConnectionSendSynchronousRequest + 272
    3   CFNetwork                       0x266d62fe +[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:] + 94
    4   Foundation                      0x27b95180 -[NSData(NSData) initWithContentsOfURL:] + 204
    5   Foundation                      0x27b9509e +[NSData(NSData) dataWithContentsOfURL:] + 42
    6   Vivimat                         0x000d7656 0x8d000 + 304726
    7   libdispatch.dylib               0x38eefe2e _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
    8   libdispatch.dylib               0x38efb810 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1572
    9   libdispatch.dylib               0x38efb1ea _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 94
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39084e0c _pthread_wqthread + 1024
    11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x390849fc start_wqthread + 8

    Thread 4:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38fe888c __workq_kernreturn + 8
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39084e18 _pthread_wqthread + 1036
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x390849fc start_wqthread + 8

    Thread 5:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38fe888c __workq_kernreturn + 8
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39084e18 _pthread_wqthread + 1036
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x390849fc start_wqthread + 8

    Thread 6:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38fe888c __workq_kernreturn + 8
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39084e18 _pthread_wqthread + 1036
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x390849fc start_wqthread + 8

    Thread 7:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38fe888c __workq_kernreturn + 8
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39084e18 _pthread_wqthread + 1036
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x390849fc start_wqthread + 8

    Thread 8:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38fe888c __workq_kernreturn + 8
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39084e18 _pthread_wqthread + 1036
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x390849fc start_wqthread + 8

    Thread 9 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
    Thread 9:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38fd3fbc mach_msg_trap + 20
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38fd3dbc mach_msg + 40
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x26e1848c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 136
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x26e16812 __CFRunLoopRun + 1050
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x26d690d8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 516
    5   CoreFoundation                  0x26d68ecc CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
    6   CFNetwork                       0x266d5d9e +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 486
    7   Foundation                      0x27c2c36c __NSThread__start__ + 1144
    8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39086c7e _pthread_body + 138
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39086bf2 _pthread_start + 110
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39084a08 thread_start + 8

    Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
        r0: 0x3bdf9e00    r1: 0x2b997fde      r2: 0x00127548      r3: 0x1751a9b0
        r4: 0x001377b4    r5: 0x0011a925      r6: 0x17519fa0      r7: 0x00243ba8
        r8: 0x3bdf9e00    r9: 0x1c7a0365     r10: 0x1751a9b0     r11: 0x1751a560
        ip: 0x00003944    sp: 0x00243b68      lr: 0x0009aa1d      pc: 0x387d7af6
      cpsr: 0x20000030
```

Many thanks

Comment: Already checked this question and answers there? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327082/exc-bad-access-signal-received

Comment: Search for information on how to symbolicate your crash.  You need to translate all the "Vivimat" addresses into symbols to know what's going on.  The main clue at the moment is `objc_msgSend` which usually means you're sending a message to an object that has been released or to one that doesn't implement the method that the message is selecting.